# Magento 2 - Updating Product list page Layout

Tags: magento2, layout, catalog, product-list, layout-update

So, I'm trying to update the **product list page** to my own custom layout inside of Magento 2.

Files I've made inside of my theme are as follows:

> /app/design/frontend/Theme/default/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

and I've created the following:

> /app/design/frontend/Theme/default/Magento_Theme/page_layout/2columns-cat.xml

Inside of my catalog_category_view.xml, which i know is the correct handle i've added the following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-cat" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

I know its using this handle, because i can cause an error by editing this xml file.

I have also updated and added it into the *** layouts.xml*** like so:

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
<layout id="2columns-cat">
    <label translate="true">2 Column left Cat</label>
</layout>
```

And here is my 2columns-cat xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-cat" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

But it isn't updating the layout. It remains a 2column-left and doesn't use the 2column-cat. Am i doing something wrong? All caches are flushed - cleared the gen folder - cleared the cache folder, nothing.

Can't think of what might not be causing the layout change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your custom layout in `<theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/layouts.xml`?

Example:

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="2columns-cat">
        <label translate="true">2 Columns Category Page</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

There are more examples on [this dev docs page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html).

Comment: Yes sorry did this as well.

Comment: Hmm in that case I'm not sure. Can you add the contents of your page layout plz? And is there anything in your logs?

Comment: Nothing in logs. I can't even change the layout to a 1column either.

Comment: @andyjones Try removing `<body>`, I don't think it's allowed inside page layouts. Also try adding `<update handle="2columns-left"/>` and see if that makes a difference. I feel like it's ignoring your layout due to an error that isn't logged any where.

Comment: nope, removing body didn't work, and update handle simply rendered a blank page. Stupid thing!! >:( what makes me think it isn't me, is that i can't even change it to 2 column-right